# Does go mod require you to pull an entire module, including transitive dependencies?

Tags: go, kubernetes, go-modules

If I have a simple import such as:

```
import (
     "hello.io/example/client"
)
```

... should I assume that `go mod tidy` by definition, will try to “import” (or more precisely transitively resolve) *all* of

```
hello.io/example/
```

?

## Details

In my case, I only need to import a few files from the `example/client` directory shown above.  Is there a straight forward way to do this?  Some ideas I had:

- make a separate git repo for `hello.io/example/client` and `hello.io/example/server`.  This obviously has drawbacks.
- make a separate go.mod for example/client and example/server.
- use some kind of go mod *magic* to tell go mod "only worry about importing things from the directory referenced in the `import` clause.

I would prefer the 3rd option, but I don't  see anything in `go mod` documentation about wether or not importing a subfolder from an external project is allowed.

## Summary of the problem statement

So to summarize, the more detailed version of this question is *does go mod tidy have the ability to only import certain parts of a dependency, or is it an all or nothing operation, and if the latter, what is the best way to carve up dependencies so as not to "import the world" when simply depending on a few files in a monorepo ?*.

I've also tagged this question as "kubernetes" because, specifically, it pertains to the more detailed example here: https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kpng/issues/58 .

Comment: importing will pull the whole module in, and its dependencies. However the resulting binary will only include the used bits, not everything.

Comment: go.mod doesn’t import anything, it declares dependencies. Only packages are imported.

Comment: Thanks for disambiguating jim … in any case  the dependency declaration , seems to have similar effects to a global import —- implicitly transitively grab packages, somehow ?

Comment: Thanks burak, that helps, what workarounds do you do to minimize the global transitive pulling ?

Comment: Updated question to reflect better terminology use

Comment: [Go Proverbs](https://go-proverbs.github.io/): "A little copying is better than a little dependency". If possible, just copy the small amount of code that you need, instead of depending on some huge monorepo.

Comment: I saw a few downvotes so I updated the question again to improve the title...

Comment: Does the solution of Volker help you?

Answer (score 3):

> does go mod tidy have the ability to only import certain parts of a dependency [?]

No. It's either a dependency in which case the package is used or it's not a dependency. Note that files have no real meaning for Go and cannot be imported, used, tested, distributed, etc. (except as part of their package).